# CSS transform:scale() and print to PDF broken

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf-generation

I'm using Chrome to generate a PDF : everything works well until some of the `divs` contain the following CSS transform used to scale down their content :

```
transform-origin: 0px 0px;
transform: scale(0.5);
```

An example of broken page is available [here](http://178.79.157.7/poc-charts-2.html) and the full code is available at the end of this post.

This example creates two `Letter` pages; each page contains two `divs` side by side that cover the full height of each `Letter` page. The content of the right `div` is scaled down using the CSS transform. All looks good in the browser. But when printing the page (either via Chrome headless or via the browser print feature), **the height** of the scaled down `div` is wrong on the first page (its content is properly scaled down).

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>

        @page {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            size: Letter portrait;
        }

        body {
            overflow: auto;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .page {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            width: 8.5in;
            height: 11in;
            break-after: page;
        }

        .widget {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: calc(8.5in / 2);
            height: 11in;
        }

        .widgetScaled {
            opacity: 0.6;
            position: absolute;
            left: calc(8.5in / 2);
            top: 0px;
            width: calc(8.5in * 2);
            height: calc(11in * 2);
            transform-origin: 0px 0px;
            transform: scale(0.5);
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 96px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">
    <div class="widget" style="background-color: beige;">
        <span class="title">1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="widgetScaled" style="background-color: beige">
        <span class="title">1scaled</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page">
    <div class="widget" style="background-color: lightblue;">
        <span class="title">2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="widgetScaled" style="background-color: lightblue;">
        <span class="title">2scaled</span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit : the issue happens only with all the pages but the last and it seems related to scaleY only (scaleX seems to be working fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the proposal mentioned in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1501807, the following fixed the issue:

```
.page {
   contain: size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing position absolute to relative from "widgetScaled" class will fix the issue.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      @page {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        size: Letter portrait;
      }

      body {
        overflow: auto;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .page {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 8.5in;
        height: 11in;
        break-after: page;
      }

      .widget {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: calc(8.5in / 2);
        height: 11in;
      }

      .widgetScaled {
        opacity: 0.6;
        position: relative;
        left: calc(8.5in / 2);
        top: 0px;
        width: calc(8.5in * 2);
        height: calc(11in * 2);
        transform-origin: 0px 0px;
        transform: scale(0.5);
      }

      .title {
        font-size: 96px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="widget" style="background-color: beige">
        <span class="title">1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="widgetScaled" style="background-color: beige">
        <span class="title">1scaled</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page">
      <div class="widget" style="background-color: lightblue">
        <span class="title">2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="widgetScaled" style="background-color: lightblue">
        <span class="title">2scaled</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="widget" style="background-color: beige">
        <span class="title">1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="widgetScaled" style="background-color: beige">
        <span class="title">1scaled</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the widgets cannot be 'relative' positioned.